# Confused about the way Leetcode displays binary trees?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm currently practicing binary tree exercises on Leetcode and am often confused. I'm currently solving this [excercise](https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/). And one of the test cases is displayed as `[1, null,2, null,3]`. I can not figure out what kind of binary tree this should be. When printing the tree does Leetcode simply omit some null nodes? Does the node with the value `3` belong to the node with the value `2`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a level-ordered traversal of the tree, the array elements go in each open slot you encounter, so:

```
           1
          / \
       null  2
            / \
         null  3
```